# how to make Angular SEO optimized website?

Tags: angular, seo

hi my website program language is angular but google can not see my website's content and when i use Ctlr + U on browser it shows none of my website's content how can i build SEO optimized Angular website?
my website is: https://behinesazan.co

can someone have a project on Github that I can use for angular that shows my content to search engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Server-side rendering (SSR) with Angular Universal the link is
https://angular.io/guide/universal
in this article there is a github link as well you can download it and use it.
but the difference is you will run it on a port rather than just a html file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.